# Filter columns using multiple conditions in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I need to write a pig script where I am finding the average values of several columns and getting only those rows whose all column values are greater than the computed averages. My script is:

```
i2 = GROUP i1 all;
i3 = FOREACH i2 GENERATE AVG(i1.user_followers_count) AS avg_user_followers_count, AVG(i1.avl_user_follower_following_ratio) AS avg_avl_user_follower_following_ratio, AVG(i1.user_total_liked) AS avg_user_total_liked, AVG(i1.user_total_posts) AS avg_user_total_posts, AVG(i1.user_total_public_lists) AS avg_user_total_public_lists, AVG(i1.avl_user_total_retweets) AS avg_avl_user_total_retweets, AVG(i1.avl_user_total_likes) AS avl_user_total_likes, AVG(i1.avl_user_total_replies) AS avg_avl_user_total_replies, AVG(i1.avl_user_engagements) AS avl_avl_user_engagements, AVG(i1.user_reply_to_reply_count) AS avg_user_reply_to_reply_count;

top_inf = FILTER i1 BY (i1.user_followers_count > i3.avg_user_followers_count, i1.avl_user_total_retweets > i3. avg_avl_user_total_retweets, i1.avl_user_total_likes > i3.avg_avl_user_total_retweets);
```

But this throws an error:

```
ERROR 1200: <file user.pig, line 70, column 103>  mismatched input '>' expecting RIGHT_PAREN
```

What is the right way to filter rows on multiple conditions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use AND to separate the conditions

```
top_inf = FILTER i1 BY (i1.user_followers_count > i3.avg_user_followers_count) 
                   AND (i1.avl_user_total_retweets > i3.avg_avl_user_total_retweets) 
                   AND (i1.avl_user_total_likes > i3.avg_avl_user_total_retweets);
```

Comment: Do we need those braces around each AND condition?